# Optimization of XGBoost Hyperparameters ValueError: The label must consist of integer labels of form 0, 1, 2, ..., [num_class - 1]

Tags: python, xgboost, random-seed, hyperparameters

I'm doing some basic hyperparameter optimization for an xgboost model and have run across the following issue. Firstly my code:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OrdinalEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, accuracy_score
import xgboost as xgb
from functools import partial
from skopt import space, gp_minimize

<Some preprocessing...> 

x = Oe.fit_transform(x)
y = Ly.fit_transform(y)


def optimize(params, param_names, x, y):
    params = dict(zip(params, param_names))
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2)
    nc = len(set(y_train))
    xgb_model = xgb.XGBClassifier(use_label_encoder=False, num_class=nc+1, objective="multi:softprob", **params)
    xgb_model.fit(X_train, y_train)
    preds = xgb_model.predict(X_test)
    acc = accuracy_score(y_test, preds)
    return -1.0 * acc


param_space = [
    space.Integer(3, 10, name="max_depth"),
    space.Real(0.01, 0.3, prior="uniform", name="learning_rate"),
]

param_names = [
    "max_depth",
    "learning_rate"
]

optimization_function = partial(
    optimize,
    param_names,
    x=x,
    y=y
)

result = gp_minimize(
    optimization_function,
    dimensions=param_space,
    n_calls=30,
    n_random_starts=6,
    verbose=True
)

print(dict(zip(param_names, result.x)))
```

After doing some searching myself, I realized that if I don't use a `random_state` on my train test split, in order to have a deterministic result, then I risk getting a `y_train` that doesn't contain labels in form of 0,1,2 ... thus getting the following error
`ValueError: The label must consist of integer labels of form 0, 1, 2, ..., [num_class - 1].`

On the other hand, if I use a random state then my optimization implementation that I use here loses its purpose since I will always have the same result, considering I'm using a **small** dataset.

And indeed after running my code with `random_state=0` for example, after 3 iterations of gp_minimize, I end up getting the same optimum no matter what combination of hyperparameters it produces.

**Update:** One could argue that even if I chose different random states, the optimal combination that I would get, would also depend on that set of random states, so in the end I only want to know if this is the right approach to optimize my model.

Comment: What is the distribution of your classes in `y`?  Probably it's sufficient to set `stratify=y` in the splitter?  I wonder whether letting the gaussian process use different splits for each hyperparameter set is a good idea though...doesn't that risk promoting/demoting a hyperparameter point just due to a lucky/unlucky split?

Comment: @BenReiniger I’ve just started exploring Data Science, so if I say something that doesn’t make sense, please bear with me.

See the problem is that my dataset is so small (14x16) I don’t even think I could make a good assumption when it comes the distribution of the y variable. 

Regarding your second point, if you read my last paragraph I was contemplating myself wether this makes sense or not. But then again as I said after 3 iterations with the same split I get an accuracy of 100%, so that’s what made me think that my model could be overfitted and led me to try and use different splits.

Comment: @BenReiniger also could you explain why stratify isn’t used in most cases when train/test split is done? At least I haven’t seen it in any implementation so far

Comment: I can't imagine xgboost doing very well with only 14 rows, especially with more than one class.  I've almost always seen `stratify` used; with big datasets it doesn't matter much, because randomness is likely to make roughly even splits anyway, but for small datasets it can be useful to try harder to enforce the same class distribution.

Comment: @BenReiniger thanks a lot for the explanation. Yeah it’s quite clear to me that xgboost won’t perform well with 14 rows. I’ll give stratify a shot and see if it solves my problem.